# The word "faith" in Matthew 17:20, Matthew 21:21 according to Reformed?

Tags: reformed-theology, gospel-of-matthew, faith

Matthew 17:20

> And He said to them, "Because of the littleness of your faith; for
>   truly I say to you, if you have faith the size of a mustard seed, you
>   will say to this mountain, 'Move from here to there,' and it will
>   move; and **nothing will be impossible to you**.

Matthew 21:21

> And Jesus answered and said to them, "Truly I say to you, if you have
>   faith and do not doubt, you will not only do what was done to the fig
>   tree, but even if you say to this mountain, 'Be taken up and cast into
>   the sea,' it will happen.

In my own understanding (as a non Christian),

- "moving a mountain" is a hyperbolic sentence where it means do
  something X where X in general point of view is impossible to happen.
  (and if it happen, it's not necessary whether there is a logical
  explanation or not).
- The verse is talking about the power of mind where in a "religious
  way" maybe it will be something like this: (a) *because God with me,
  I believe (have faith) that I can do it* ---not--- (b) *because I
  believe (have faith) in God, God will do it after I ask Him*, 
  although both (a) and (b) can leads to [*nothing will be impossible to
  me*].

As the two points above is a non-Christian thinking, that's why I ask the question here if there is a "deeper" explanation about the sentence in that verse then what is it according to the Reformed Church?

Comment: @4castle, I've edited the question. Now it's referring to the Reformed Church. I hope there won't be a different answer within Reformed Church itself ---> for example, Reformed-A say that "moving a mountain" literally means "abracadabra" where in a second the mountain move to different location (something like telekinesis) while Reformed-B say different things. Thank you for your suggestion. :).